# ng-model undefined in nested drop-down in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and I try to code a page to create teams and assign players to those teams. 
I put a `select` tag to select a player to add to the team. I've created a [Fiddle with the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13350/).
I think there is a $scope issue, but i don't see what it can be.
Any ideas?

Comment: Made a few updates, seems to be working as expected now: Check this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/918ffmgx/

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, you save my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `ng-model="selectedPlayer[team.name]"` without setting `selectedPlayer` in scope at all. To use it like this you first need to create variable `$scope.selectedPlayer = {};`

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L721ap6d/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that exactly what was missing!